# When are files updated?

Tags: python, json

I have a set of code which runs in an infinite loop, cancelled through terminal with control C. In this code I use the code `json.dumps(dictionary,outfile)`

I have noticed that this does not actually put the data into the file until I have used control C to terminate the process. Why does the file not update until after the program has terminated?

Comment: I think we need a bit more code to give you a precise answer. 
I can however tell you that most modification are cached before being written to disk in bulk, to save a lot of I/O time. You can force the flush by calling `outfile.flush()` usually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anthony Rossi is basically right, you need to flush the data using `outfile.flush()`. But why is that so?

`json.dump` expects a "a .write()-supporting file-like object", see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump). Somewhere in your code, you have used `open` to get your `outfile`. If we have a look at the documentation for [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open), we can read the following:

> buffering is an optional integer used to set the buffering policy. Pass 0 to switch buffering off (only allowed in binary mode), 1 to select line buffering (only usable in text mode), and an integer > 1 to indicate the size in bytes of a fixed-size chunk buffer. When no buffering argument is given, the default buffering policy works as follows:
>
> - Binary files are buffered in fixed-size chunks; the size of the buffer is chosen using a heuristic trying to determine the underlying device’s “block size” and falling back on io.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE. On many systems, the buffer will typically be 4096 or 8192 bytes long.
> - “Interactive” text files (files for which isatty() returns True) use line buffering. Other text files use the policy described above for binary files.

I guess you haven't specified the `buffering` parameter and your data is smaller than 4 / 8 kb. Therefore, the write is buffered and not directly written to the file.

When you kill your program using `Ctrl+C`, the `outfile` is closed and flushes the data to your file.

To fix this, simply put `outfile.flush()` after your `json.dump()` as Anthony Rossi suggested.

Comment: Ok thank you, yeah I had not specified a buffering parameter and as such it only flushed the data once I terminated the program.